# how to make latte dock (0.6.x) opaque/not transparent?

Tags: kde, dock, kde5

I've looked at various latte dock screenshots and they look similar to Gnome dock but I am using latte dock 0.6.x and I cannot see a way to make dock opaque/not transparent.

Any ideas on how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Appearance page, enable option (Show Panel Background) and increase the slider underneath to 100%

if this is isnt working then either your plasma theme is full transparent try Breeze Dark as a test
or
you are using Latte as a widget on the desktop, try to run it through an app launcher